# How to skip an iteration if no data is found in API call

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Apps Script, I'm using some code I adapted from a project I found. It calls an API endpoint and lays out the data in a spreadsheet. I was able to get it to loop through multiple API calls in order to pull data from multiple documents. However, the code breaks if it finds a document with no data. In this case, I want it to just skip that iteration and start again at the next `cardIds.forEach` iteration.

Here's a link to a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/174fzw7HAheDMmSxZigILcW2CVdfiGkWTlcY8yrrWL98/edit?usp=sharing).

I tried:

```
 if (response == "") {
    return;
  }
```

But no dice. Here's the full code (also it's very inefficient. I have params on their twice because I'm not sure how to consolidate them with all the functions inside other functions..)

```js
const DATA_SHEET = "Data";
const USERNAME_CELL = "B1";
const API_TOKEN_CELL = "B2";
const CARD_ID_COL = "Cards!B:B"
const DATA_RANGE = "A4:C"

var getNextPage = function(response) {
  var url = response.getAllHeaders().Link;
  if (!url) {
    return "";
  }
  return /<([^>]+)/.exec(url)[1];
};

var getIt = function(path, username, apiToken) {
  var params = {
    "method": "GET",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + apiToken),
      "x-guru-application": "spreadsheet",
      "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "GApp=spreadsheet"
    }
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(path, params);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  // check if there's another page of results.
  var nextPage = getNextPage(response);
  if (nextPage) {
    data.nextPage = nextPage;
  };
  
  return data;
};

var getItAll = function(url, username, apiToken, callback) {
  var data = [];
  
  while (url) {
    var page = getIt(url, username, apiToken);
    
    var startIndex = data.length;
    page.forEach(function(a) {
      data.push(a);
    });
    
    // get the url of the next page of results.
    url = page.nextPage;
    
    if (callback) {
      // the second parameter is whether we're done or not.
      // if there's a url for the next page that means we're not done yet.
      callback(data, startIndex, page.length, url ? false : true);
    }
  }
  
  return data;
};

function eachCard() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(DATA_SHEET);
  sheet.getRange(DATA_RANGE).clearContent();

  var username = sheet.getRange(USERNAME_CELL).getValue();
  var apiToken = sheet.getRange(API_TOKEN_CELL).getValue();
  var cardIds = sheet.getRange(CARD_ID_COL).getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!="");

  var params = {
    "method": "GET",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + apiToken),
      "x-guru-application": "spreadsheet",
      "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "GApp=spreadsheet"
    }
  };

  cardIds.forEach(function (cardId) {
    var fullUrl = "https://api.getguru.com/api/v1/cards/"+cardId+"/comments"
    var cardComments = getItAll(fullUrl, username, apiToken);

    var fullUrl = "https://api.getguru.com/api/v1/cards/"+cardId+"/extended"
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fullUrl, params);
    var cardData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    
    var sheetLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A" + sheetLastRow);
    if (range.getValue() !== "") {
      var lastRow = sheetLastRow+1;
    } else {
      var lastRow = range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow()+1;
    }

    cardComments.forEach(function(comment, commentIndex) {
      sheet.getRange(lastRow + commentIndex, 1).setValue(comment.dateCreated);
      sheet.getRange(lastRow + commentIndex, 1 + 1).setValue(comment.content);
      sheet.getRange(lastRow + commentIndex, 1 + 2).setValue(cardData.preferredPhrase);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a sample sheet for testing?

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz Just updated with a sample sheet!